# Generate a thumbnailed gallery with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

First, sorry for bad english :-)

On a little website i own, i would like to show the users an image gallery with thumbnails using Fancybox.
But, on the page opening the fancybox, i don't have the links to the images. (because there are a lot of images).

So, i tried something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
    $.fancybox(
        [ 
            {href : 'rep/img01.jpg', rel : 'fancybox-thumb', class : 'fancybox-thumb'}, 
            {href : 'rep/img02.jpg', rel : 'fancybox-thumb', class : 'fancybox-thumb'} 
        ],
        {
            type : 'image',
            autoScale : true,
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',
            thumbs: {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }               
    );
});
```

It opens my gallery but no thumbnails :-(
Hope i'm clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thumbs` is a sub-option of the option `helpers` so your code should be like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox([{
        href: 'rep/img01.jpg',
        rel: 'fancybox-thumb',
        class: 'fancybox-thumb'
    }, {
        href: 'rep/img02.jpg',
        rel: 'fancybox-thumb',
        class: 'fancybox-thumb'
    }], {
        // API options
        type: 'image',
        autoScale: true,
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        helpers: {
            thumbs: {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            } //  thumbs
        } //  helpers
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```